# Move and organize rows from main worksheet into multiple/respective sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For starters, I am a complete beginner at using Apps Scripts for Google Sheets at my new workplace, and we do not have an IT department who can help us create this file. I am trying to create a shared file that can be accessed by our client, our service technicians, and our main office simultaneously, so I opted to create a Google Sheet.

I am hoping to automate this process to prevent users (except myself) from needing to manually edit, move and sort data across multiple sheets that might cause the file to break or become inconsistent. For this to work, I need users to only be able to create entries in our 'main' worksheet and only view the other sheets. From here, I'd like to automate the file to move rows to specific sheets named after each unit when it's marked "DONE", and also organize each unit's sheet by the date column. Our intention is for these sheets to provide us with a running history of all the work that has been done each unit.

NOTE: I have 54 units and counting and I currently will have to copy & paste the code multiple times and edit each one to match the unit numbers. I currently have a one unit set-up, but I think there's something wrong with the code or the triggers I have set-up as it does not automatically sort the destination sheet. Either way, I think there has to be a simpler way to do this.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Here's the code that I've used thus far:

```
    function trailer27() {
  // moves a row from a sheet to another when a magic value is entered in a column
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
  // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/ehoCZjFPBao/discussion

  var sheetNameToWatch = "WORKSHEET";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 6;2 // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "Yes";"27"
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "27"
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    }
}

function Sort27() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("27")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:F1000");

 // Sorts by the values in column 1 (J)
 range.sort({column: 1, descending: false});
}

function SortWorksheet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("WORKSHEET")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:F1000");

 // Sorts by the values in column 10 (J)
 range.sort({column: 1, descending: false});
}

function undoMove() {
  // moves a row from a sheet to another when a magic value is entered in a column
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
  // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/ehoCZjFPBao/discussion

  var sheetNameToWatch = "27"

  var columnNumberToWatch = 6; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "CALLED"; "EMAIL"
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "WORKSHEET";
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant to be an onEdit function it's worth using the event object even considering the difficulty in debugging

```
function trailer27(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheetNameToWatch = "WORKSHEET";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 6; 2 // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "Yes"; "27"
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "27"
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && e.range.columnStart == columnNumberToWatch && e.value == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I think I am biting off more than I can chew considering I've never done anything like this before. I'd have to do some more reading on this! Thanks for taking the time to respond!